# Cannot Modify Non Const Member in Class

Tags: c++, class

I try to modify one specific method in OpenCV. In the class definition;

```
class CV_EXPORTS CvANN_MLP : public CvStatModel
... 
protected
...
int activ_func;
```

when I try to modify activ_func field, I get:

```
error: assignment of data-member in read-only structure
```

error, however it is not defined as const, how is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you didn't give the context of the assignment statement itself. But I'm guessing that you're trying to assign to `activ_func` from a `const` member function.